# Difference in arithmetic and geometric mean to combine two images

Tags: image-processing, mean

I want to know which mean (arithmetic or geometric) is better to combine two grayscale images and why? I know the difference in arithmetic and geometric mean mathematically, but for combining two digital images, which mean to use and what is the logic behind it...I am unable to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Empirical answer...

If you start with top-to-bottom and left-to-right gradient images, like this:

[image][image]

You will get this with an arithmetic mean:

[image]

And this with a geometric mean:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can know is that because of the [Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

is that the geometric mean will give you a darker image than the arithmetic one.

When you use the mean to combine the images using the arithmetic mean will give you the middle between the two images while the geometric one will give you an image that will be lean more to the dark values.